# simple redirect to default page with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, url, .htaccess, dynamic-url

The htaccess file requires an entry at the end of `/folder/` to redirect the page
example:
`http://www.server.com/folder/"some-page-name"`

If no page is defined as, then I want it to be "index" by default

the htacess

```
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/index.php/?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# there must be something after /folder/ for this to work
RewriteBase ^/folder/(.+)$  /folder/subfolder/index.php/?page=$1 [L]

# if there isn't, do a catch-all redirect (change to whatever "index by default" means)
RewriteRule ^/folder/$      /folder/index
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the file exists or not and redirect the users to the index (if is does not), use the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond .* index [R=301]
```

Comment: This would also work, but its syntax is kind of weird and it requires Apache to hit the file stat cache on every request.